# "input is not a PCH file" - Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, pch

I'm working on a client code using PCH a file and I have this errors.

> error: input is not a PCH file:
>   '/Users/XXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Stockfish-gmtlyxbgbyyplbgwrhzsazbjjtxp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/2449868381699930613/Stockfish_Prefix.pch.gch'
>   fatal error: file
>   '/Users/XXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Stockfish-gmtlyxbgbyyplbgwrhzsazbjjtxp/Build/Intermediates.noindex/PrecompiledHeaders/SharedPrecompiledHeaders/2449868381699930613/Stockfish_Prefix.pch.gcinput
>   is not a PCH file:

I tried removing derived data, clean et rebuild but i still have this error. It was working a few months ago.

Any idea what's wrong?

EDIT: [build settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SGXgH.png)

Comment: What is the Xcode version are you using?

Comment: Hi, Xcode 10.1!

Comment: Open the Xcode project, Try to do the following steps, XCode->File->Workspace Settings->Build System, select the option "Legacy Build System".

Comment: It seems to work, thank you very much!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution find by AshokPolu:

> Open the Xcode project, Try to do the following steps, XCode->File->Workspace Settings->Build System, select the option "Legacy Build System".

Answer (score 0):

The error in this case is quite self explanatory. If you have a look at the very end of the message you posted, it says `Stockfish_Prefix.pch.gcinput` is not a PCH file. This is correct, as it has `gcinput` as it's file extension. My first step to debugging this would be to go into your build settings and search for `pre-compiled`. Make sure the file that it specifies exists, and that the extension is `.pch`.

Comment: Hi, i added a screenshot of my build settings. The extension is .pch and I have no idea where the .gch come from..